# diagonalizable question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a ﬁnite dimensional complex vector space. Let $T : V → V$ be a diagonalizable, linear map. For each positive integer $k$ we write $T^k = T ◦···◦T$, the $k$-fold composition of the map $T$. With this notation, we can deﬁne $p(T) := a_0 I_V + a_1T +···+ a_nT^n$, whenever $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + ··· + a_nx^n$ is a polynomial with complex coeﬃcients $a_0,\dots,a_n$.

Question: I already showed that  $p(λ)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(T)$. How can I prove that if $β$ is a basis of $V$ then $p([T])$ respect from $β$ to $β$ is diagonalizable for any polynomial $p(x)$ with complex coeﬃcients. Deduce that $p(T)$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: $T$ diagonalizable $\Rightarrow$ there is a basis of eigenvectors for $T$, but each eigenvector for $T$ is an eigenvector for $p(T)$ (with the eigenvalue $p(\lambda)$) $\Rightarrow$ there is a basis of eigenvectors for $p(T)$ $\Rightarrow$ $p(T)$ diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the matrix $[T]_{\beta \to \beta}$. With the notation $p(A) = a_0 I + a_1 A + a_2 A^2 + \cdots + a_n A^n$, your question is asking you to show $p(A)$ is diagonalizable.

By assumption $A$ is diagonalizable, so it can be written as $PDP^{-1}$ for some invertible $P$ and diagonal $D$. Then $A^k = P D^k P^{-1}$ for any positive integer $k$. Do you see how this implies $p(A)$ is diagonalizable?